# Segregating objects into mat-tabs based on instance variable

Tags: angular, angular2-template

**Angular 5**

I have 2 tabs in a `mat-tab-group` and each tab contains a `mat-table`. There is an array of objects being fetched into a `datasource` which is used to populate these `mat-table`s .Each object has a variable, say x, which can take a value equal to either 1 or 2.

If x=1 for an object, it should go into the first tab, else, the second.

How can I do this?

Current structure:

```
<mat-tab-group>
        <mat-tab label="tab1">
          <div>
            <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
            ...
            </mat-table>
          </div>
        </mat-tab>
        <mat-tab label="tab2">
          <div>
            <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
            ...
            </mat-table>
          </div>
        </mat-tab>
<mat-tab-group>
```

Note: I guess this could be done using inline template variables, but don't know how. Open to accepting better solutions as well, if any.

Comment: You can try this <mat-tab-group [selectedIndex]="dataSource.x"></mat-tab-group>

Comment: Thanks! I tried this but all my tabs are being populated with the same data. No segregation is happening

Comment: Can you provide some examples of your data

Comment: I have a class 'Event' which has an instance variable 'time'. Say ev is an Event object, I tried <mat-tab-group [selectedIndex]="dataSource.time"> where dataSource is being filled by an array of Event objects. This didnt work

Comment: Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: So you want from one array to populate 2 different tables where one tab will have all object with x = 1 and another one with x = 2?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169309/discussion-between-lkpark-and-rahul-saha).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you will not able to have one data source for all tabs, you will need to have unique for each.

Like a solution, I would prepare first all your data, by grouping it by the "x" param.

On the next step transform all grouped data into MatTableDataSource objects.

The final step would be the use of *ngFor just to render all the "mat-tab" for each individual group.